# Tuples in cassandra before Cassandra 3.0

Tags: cassandra

Do tuples without non-frozen keywords also supported before Cassandra 3.0?

before Cassandra 3.0

```
 create table abc(t tuple<int,text> primary key)
```

does the above query correct or we have to use frozen like below query?

```
 create table abc(t frozen<tuple<int,text>> primary key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have it `(t int, v text, PRIMARY KEY ((t,v)))` ? You can use a composite partition key which gives you more query options and easier to use.

You cant have non frozen collections as your partition key, it doesn't make sense (partition key cant change) but [tuples are frozen implicitly](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html#tuples) so even if you dont specify it:

```
create table basic.abc(t tuple<int,text> primary key)

desc table basic.abc

CREATE TABLE basic.abc (
    t frozen<tuple<int, text>> PRIMARY KEY
) ...
```

User Defined Types are an option for readability as well.